# Changing a hard coded value in a PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, html

Scenario: I have an insert .php file to insert into applicant table: (columns: `firstname`, `lastname` and `class`) from a PHP form I created. However there is a third column that is hard coded in the php file: `class`.

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO applicant(firstname, lastname, class) 
VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','Computer');`

From time to time I may want to change the value from computer. Is there a way for me to change it without having to open the PHP file? For example, can I change it by entering a value into an HTML form?

Comment: create a new 'secret' webform/page, which has a form that writes this new value to a file say `text.txt`. now, in insert.php, use a file read function, to read and grab the value inside `text.txt` and use it as a variable, say `$thirdColumn`. Use this in your INSERT query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of going too deep too fast I would extend the class you don't want to use EG: the class that says:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO applicant(firstname, lastname, class) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','Computer');
```

Could be `extended` to be a class where the 3rd value is a `parameter` or a `preset value` for the new class.

Also I would alter the un-extended class to look like this to avoid INJECTION attacks

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO applicant(firstname, lastname, class) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[firstname])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[lastname])."','Computer');
```

Comment: by making a new file to extend it, and like everyone says, you're really not in good form without the injection avoidance

Answer (score 1):

That is really bad practice. This opens up for SQL Injection and Cross Site Scripting attack. To answer your question, yes. You can do just that with what you provided and use what you did wrong to your advantage.

Here is what you have:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO applicant(firstname, lastname, class) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','Computer');
```

Here is what I can do
In you textbox for $_POST['firstname'], `'; INSERT INTO applicant(firstname, lastname, class) VALUES('$NEWVALUE', '$newValue', '$newValue'); SHOW TABLES; DROP TABLE applicant; --`

Comment: Just to make your point more clear: it is bad practice to just add the POSTed values directly into the SQL query. This does not mean all queries should be static (no parameters coming from the user), just that the parameters should be verified first.

Comment: Point out to me some good practices pleas I am new to database

Comment: @user1218638 If you don't understand what Churk is saying here, he's basically using a security vulnerability in the php file to break the script. In this case he's using the attack to execute the actual query you originally wanted, but this is equivalent to "fixing" a lost car key by breaking in through the window and hot-wiring the car. Don't rely on this as a long-term fix unless you really have no other choice.

Comment: Here is a link to use mysqli and prepared statements. You prepare you insert like this: INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) VALUES(?,?); then when you execute you provide the arguments, The prepared statement will automatically render the post data to literals, so you don't even need to escape it. So you don't have overhead of mysql_escape...(). Here is a reference http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: YES, please don't use my example, its my way to show @user1218638 what is wrong and what is going to happen if he did.

Comment: To be clear, I thought this solution was ingenious, and it gave me a good laugh. It could also get the OP out of trouble if they were facing an emergency. I just wasn't sure if they understood the idea, and I imagined this making its way into some university registration system and hanging around for 20 years as legacy code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page with a Submit button and a TextBox on it. Have it store the value in an XML document, then have your code open the XML document to retrieve the value. This is, of course, assuming you want to store the value semi-permanently.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the vulnerability above, there is a way for you to switch between inserts. Create a condition on your PHP code, and check on that condition.

```
if ($_POST['use_sql'] == 1) {
 // executeSQL1;
} else {
 // executeSQL2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions on this page are clever hacks, but I'm going to be a spoilsport and say: No. You can't fix this in any way that's remotely safe or stable without editing the PHP file. Whoever wrote the PHP file took a shortcut they shouldn't have taken, and now you've got a script that you can't extend in a reasonable way.

If you can get access to the PHP file, all you need to do is change:

```
'computer'
```

to

```
'$_POST[class]'
```

And then if you have a field in your input form called "class," its value will go into the class column.

If the problem is that you can edit files on the server, but for some reason you can't edit *that particular* PHP file, you could always make a new PHP file that has the same contents, make the change you need, and direct your input form there instead (just change the ACTION attribute of the form to point to the new PHP file instead of the old one).